# Is $p^s$ transcendental if $\zeta(s)=0$?

Tags: analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ its ring of integers.

Let

$$\zeta_{K}(s)=\prod_{\mathfrak{m}}\frac{1}{1-\#(\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{m})^{-s}}$$
be the $\zeta$ function associated to $K$ (more precisely: the analytic continuation thereof to the complex plane).

Let $p$ be a prime and $s$ a zero of $\zeta_{K}$ with $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.

**Question**: Is $p^s$ transcendental?

This would of course be true $s$ were algebraic, as a consequence if the Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

I believe that all such zeros are at least conjectured to be transcendental.

Comment: That equation doesn't work for $Re(s)<1$, in my understanding.

Comment: What is $\#(y)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: The number of elements of the residue class field.

Comment: Cross-posted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436425/is-p-s-transcendental-if-zetas-0). When cross-posting, all version must be linked together to prevent the duplication of work.